# Apache Tomcat server on linux

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

I have installed java and tomcat appache  server on linux.
When i am going to start tomcat using ./startup.sh command on linux server,
it gives output as

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.28
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.28
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.28/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/src/jdk1.6.0_16
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/src/apache-tomcat-5.5.28/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

but server is not started.

after that when i am firing javac command ,it generates following error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

i am not getting the right reason for that.
I am new with linux.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not reserve enough space for object heap.

Looks like there is not enough memory given for the initialisation.
Check the given memory...and reconfigure your memory size for the JVM.